# The Deligne-Mumford Compactification for Closed Surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces, compactifications

I am reading [this note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2459.pdf) on super-Riemann surfaces. In the second paragraph of section 7.4.1 (page 87), there is a statement that I am trying to understand:

> The compactified moduli space of closed oriented Riemann surfaces has
>   no boundary.

However, as it is mentioned, the compactified moduli space of surfaces with boundary is an orbifold with boundary.

Can someone please elaborate these points and that why the compactified moduli space of closed oriented Riemann surfaces does not have boundaries and is just compact? A good pedagogical reference on the Deligne-Mumford compactification is highly appreciated.

Comment: In some sense Deligne and Mumford's paper is a reference for this, but I guess probably not in the sense you want...

Comment: _why the compactified moduli space of closed oriented Riemann surfaces does not have boundaries and is just compact_ As written, this is a tautology --- it is compact because it is the compactification of something. Maybe a better way to ask the question is why the Deligne--Mumford compactification is _modular_, that is, why the points added in actually correspond to something geometric. A reference that I like is Harris--Morrison, _Moduli of Curves_.

Comment: @Bort I understand that it is compact. I was thinking that the nodal curves added to construct the compactification considered as _boundaries_ of the DM compactification (like starting from an open disk and adding the boundary circle) but it seems that this way of thinking is not correct for closed surfaces. I am interested in doing integration by parts on the compactified space and I am wondering whether there are surface terms or not and how I should think about the _divisor_ contributions. If the compactified space is compact with no boundary, there is no boundary contribution.

Comment: An other reference might be the paper by John Hubbard and Sarah Koch called *An analytic construction of the Deligne-Mumford compactification of the moduli space of curves* https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1406552251

Comment: @MaximeScott I have read this paper, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: Your intuition of taking an open disk and adding a (real codimension one) boundary is not the right picture here. Adding boundary strata to the moduli space of curves is adding a complex codimension 1 strata. A better analogy is adding a point to $\mathbb{C}$ to get the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{CP}^1\cong S^2$ which is a compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: @JimBryan That is true. I think that intuition works for the compactification of the moduli space of Riemann surfaces with boundary possibly with marked points on the boundaries, which indeed has a boundary, as it is mentioned in the Witten's note. I am just trying to understand why DM compactification of the moduli space of surfaces without boundary does not have a boundary but DM compactification of the moduli space of Riemann surfaces with boundary does have a boundary. How can I see the difference? There are some arguments in pages 87 and 88 and I am trying to understand them better.

Comment: @QGravity. Maybe you can think about it this way. There is a real parameter associated to a boundary component of a Riemann surface with boundary (I believe given by the length of the loop using the (unique) hyperbolic metric on the  Riemann surface with boundary). This leads to a real co-dimension 1 boundary in the compactification of the moduli space. Whereas the complex structure on a Riemann surface without boundary is described solely by complex parameters (3g-3 of them) this leads to a complex co-dimension 1 boundary in the compactification of the moduli space.

Comment: @JimBryan Thank you for the answer. What you say completely makes sense to me. Thank you again.